# Mac terminal's string argument recognizes double quotation marks

Tags: python, shell, command-line, terminal

Basically i have a python file that creates a csv files given the string arguments (using concurrent/multiprocessing in the python code).

It worked perfectly fine yesterday like this:

```
> python file.py "arg 1" "arg 2" "arg 3" "arg 4" "arg 5" "arg 6"
> ls
arg 1.csv    arg 2.csv
arg 3.csv    arg 4.csv
arg 5.csv    arg 6.csv
```

However, I tried running it today again with 18 arguments and it gave my code something like this:

```
> python file.py "arg 1" "arg 2" "arg 3" ... ...  "arg 16" "arg 17" "arg 18"
> ls
"arg .csv    1".csv
...
...
...
18".csv     "arg.csv
```

It's suddenly reading "arg 1" as two arguments `"arg` and  `1"`

Did I accidentally click on some short cut key on my Mac terminal that caused this?

I haven't made any change to the python file so I don't understand why this is happening.

EDIT:

I included print(argument) in my code and now when I run the file like this on my Mac terminal:

```
> python file.py "arg 1" "arg 2" "arg 3" "arg 4" "arg 5" "arg 6"
"arg
 1"
"arg
 2"
"arg
 3"
"arg
 4"
"arg
 5"
"arg
 6"
```

it's not recognizing the string inside the double quotation marks as a one string. I'm pretty certain there has to be something to do with my Mac terminal that's causing this.

Same goes for single-quotes. It will print `'arg` and  `1'`

Putting \ in the string like `"arg\ 1"` does recognize it as one string but it still includes the double quotation marks that prints out `"arg 1"`

EDIT 2:

`main` function is what creates the .csv files given the item

```
def do_concurrent(item_1, item_2, item_3, item_4, item_5, item_6):
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            f1 = executor.submit(main, item_1)
            f2 = executor.submit(main, item_2)
            f3 = executor.submit(main, item_3)
            f4 = executor.submit(main, item_4)
            f5 = executor.submit(main, item_5)
            f6 = executor.submit(main, item_6)

item_1 = sys.argv[1]
item_2 = sys.argv[2]
item_3 = sys.argv[3]
item_4 = sys.argv[4]
item_5 = sys.argv[5]
item_6 = sys.argv[6]

do_concurrent(item_1, item_2, item_3, item_4, item_5, item_6)
```

Comment: this shouldn't happen but try inserting a backslash in between your string like this "arg\ 1" etc to see if anything changes

Comment: This needs troubleshooting. An obvious first step would be to check whether the argv passed to the Python program looks like you expect. If it doesn't, the problem is somewhere in the shell (and exactly *how* it looks might give some clue to what has gone wrong), if it does, the problem is in the Python code.

Comment: What if you use single-quotes `'`?

Comment: I have updated more details. It still recognizes the double quotation marks(and single) as part of the string and i don't know why.

Comment: What shell are you using? If you run, in your shell, `printf "x%sx\n" "hello world"`, what output do you get?

Comment: By the way, you said you did `print(argument)`, but this really tells us nothing, because `argument` is not a standard thing in Python, so we have no idea what you printed. The shell arguments get passed to the Python program as `sys.argv`. That's where you need to start looking.

Comment: oh i see, i'll have to look into it bit more. Also, it prints `xhello worldx`

Comment: The `xhello worldx` bit indicates that your shell is at least not completely insane, so I'd say it's time to start looking at `sys.argv` and see what goes on with that.

Comment: thank you!, i did update the post with the part of my code that seems to be the main source of my problem..

Comment: Could you edit that into a [minimal, complete, and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?